# The progressbar in listview item disappears when scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I have a `progessbar` appears in one of the items in the `listview`, when I scroll the `listview` (this item not visible any more). the progress bar inside it disappears and sometimes appear in another item in the `listview`. what is the problem ?

**edit:**
I am using `ViewHolder pattern` the `textviews` don't have any problem. the problem is in showing/hiding the progresssbar, because it is hidden by default, and appears according specific condition in the adapter `getView()`. I am showing the `progoressbar` programmatically using the `setVisibility()`

Comment: Are you using the [ViewHolder pattern](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) to recicle the views? If you are, maybe it could be the problem?

Comment: You can control programmatically when to make your progressbar visible and when not, using `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `setVisibility(View.GONE)` respectively.

Comment: Probably you are not setting its visibility to GONE at the right place where you should.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpfull to see some of the code in order to debug it. It could be when you scroll the focus is shifted away from the progress bar and to the list view and then possibly when you stop scrolling a different element in the list view has focus and the bar becomes registered to that elemenet. As I said some of the code or more info on what is going on would be helpful.

Comment: If you want some more clarifications about the question from the OP please ask your queries in comments, not as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

If elements are disappearing from one row and then appearing in another, it's a good bet that you're not handling ListView's recycling correctly.

For each call to createView in your Adapter, if you use the convertView parameter you must handle the case where the ProgressBar is visible as well as invisible. This case will arise when you show the ProgressBar in one row, then scroll the ListView. That row will be recycled when it scrolls off the screen, and passed back into createView as the convertView parameter. If you don't set its visibility back to 'gone', it will continue showing but now for the incorrect row.